# how can I rspec test a controller with route globbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, glob

To get a list of questionnaires I use the

```
GET "/questionnaires/user/1/public/true/mine/true/shared/true"
```

in routes.rb I have

```
/questionnaires/*myparams(.:format)  {:controller=>"questionnaires", :action=>"list"}
```

The controller uses route globbing to create a query in the list method

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate  

  def list  
    myparams = params[:myparams].split("/").to_h
  end

  # ...
end
```

I am trying to create the test cases for all the options in a spec file

```
describe "GET list" do  
  it "returns the list of questionnaires for the user" do  
    get :list  
    # ...  
  end
end
```

what I get when i run rspec is

```
Failures:

1) QuestionnairesController List GET list returns the list of questionnaires for the user
  Failure/Error: get :list
  No route matches {:controller=>"questionnaires", :action=>"list"}
  # ./spec/controllers/questionnaires_controller_spec.rb:20
```

The question is how do you write the spec file to pass the globbed parameters to rspec. I like to do something like this:

```
describe "GET list" do 
  it "returns the list of questionnaires for the user" do
    get :list, "/user/1/public/true/mine/true/shared/true"  
  end
end
```

and change the parameters to test the different cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The globbing happens in the dispatcher, so the params are already assigned when the controller is invoked. When the controller action is reached, the globbed parameters should already be split into an array in `params[:myparams]`.

If you want to test this in the controller, just set up the params hash the way the dispatcher would:

```
describe "GET 'list'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get :list,  :myparams => "user/1/public/true/mine/true/shared/true".split("/")
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up using    get :list,  :myparams => "rspec/true/user/#{@user.id}/public/true/mine/false/shared/false"   without the split, the split is done inside the controller